# How do I change the column names using dcast?

Tags: r, data.table, dcast

I'm transforming my data from long to wide. Part of the data are dates. 
My problem is that I would like to have other colnames. 
It is formed like eg variable_1-1 and I want 1-1_variable.

df:

```
    SN specimen_isolate_no isolaat materiaal_lokatie alarmniveau afnamedatum
 1:  2                 1-1  STAPEP Bloedkweek  Bloed       0      2017-04-30
 2:  3                 1-1  KLEBOX      Bloedkweek         0      2018-12-30
 3:  3                 2-1  KLEBOX      Bloedkweek         0      2018-12-31
```

I tried dcast from data.table:

```
setDT(df) 
df.wide <- dcast(df, SN ~ specimen_isolate_no, value.var = c("materiaal_lokatie","afnamedatum", "isolaat", "alarmniveau" ))
```

Which give me the following result:

```
colnames: 
[1] "SN"                    "materiaal_lokatie_1-1" "materiaal_lokatie_2-1" 
 "afnamedatum_1-1"            "afnamedatum_2-1"        "isolaat_1-1"          
      "isolaat_2-1"                  "alarmniveau_1-1"    "alarmniveau_2-1"
```

This result is ok, but I rather have the colnames formed like specimen_isolate_no_variable, eg 1-1_alarmniveau.

In order to achieve this, I tried

```
molten <- melt(df, id.vars = c("SN", "specimen_isolate_no"))
dfmolton <- dcast(molten, SN ~ specimen_isolate_no + variable)

#and 

 df %>% 
     gather(key, value, -SN, -specimen_isolate_no) %>%  
     unite(new.col, c(specimen_isolate_no,key )) %>%   
     spread(new.col, value)
```

But both options mess up my dates and I don't know how to fix that.

```
 #colnames:
 [1] "SN"                    "1-1_isolaat"           "1-1_materiaal_lokatie" "1-1_alarmniveau"       "1-1_afnamedatum"       "2-1_isolaat"           "2-1_materiaal_lokatie" "2-1_alarmniveau"      "2-1_afnamedatum"   

dfmolten$`1-1_afnamedatum`
[1] "17286" "17895"
```

So my question: does anyone how to change the forming of colnames using dcast?

Comment: I don't think you want to change the forming using `dcast` directly (though you haven't stated exactly what form you'd like the names to take -- perhaps `sep` argument is useful? though I gather not)... You can try either (1) overwriting `specimen_isolate_no` before casting or (2) using `setnames` & some `grep`/`gsub` magic to clean up afterwards

Comment: @MichaelChirico: I'm not sure I understand. I would like 1-1_variable instead of variable_1-1.

Comment: There's no functionality for it right now, unfortunately. An earlier discussion is here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1951 @MichaelChirico

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible to do this directly with dcast. You could use a function like setnames() to change columns names after using dcast(). You should drop a comment on the data.table GitHub, maybe they will add this feature in a future update.

Comment: Ok, thank you all! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Frank mentioned, there's an outstanding feature request for this... side note: please add reactions to FRs you'd like, we use this to some extent to steer development time:

https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3189

In the meantime, you can just use `setnames` and some regexing to do this:

```
old = grep('SN', names(df.wide), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
new = sapply(strsplit(old, '_', fixed = TRUE), function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse = '_'))
setnames(df.wide, old, new)
```