Customise names of columns created by dcast.data.table for multiple aggregation functions
We have (adapted from ?dcast.data.table)
library(data.table)
# multiple value.var and multiple fun.aggregate
set.seed(1)
DT = data.table(x=sample(5,20,TRUE), y=sample(2,20,TRUE),
                z=sample(letters[1:2], 20,TRUE), d1=runif(20), d2=1L)
# multiple fun.agg and value.var (one-to-one)
dcast(DT, x+y ~ z, fun.aggregate=list(sum, mean), value.var=list("d1", "d2"))

with names
[1] "x"         "y"         "d1_sum_a"  "d1_sum_b"  "d2_mean_a" "d2_mean_b"

Is there some way to automatically customize these names so, for example, the z value is the first part of the name, the value.var part is customizable (so one can use strings different from d1 and d2) and the last part of the name and the function reference is removable (as it is already determined by the value.var)? So, the output names would be
[1] "x"         "y"         "a_d1"  "b_d1"  "a_d2" "b_d2"

Question in R, customize names of columns created by dcast.data.table does not answer as there are no multiple aggregation functions, and similar for How to Use data.table dcast Renaming on one Aggregation Function
Thanks!

what are your desidered names in the case you shown? because i dont understand why the function name shouldn't be included in the name. Without it how can you distinguish the mean from the sum?

@Edo thanks for the comment. I added to my question

you can do it with tidyr::pivot_wider but I guess you want a data.table solution, dont you?

@Edo Indeed, I want a data.table solution. Anyway, thanks for the answer

Currently, it doesn't seem to be possible to do what you asked with data.table as you can see here:

https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2601
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56052255/9918265


You could do it with tidyr::pivot_wider:
tidyr::pivot_wider(DT,
                   id_cols = c(x,y), 
                   names_from = z,
                   names_glue = "{z}_{.value}",
                   values_from = c(d1,d2), 
                   values_fn = list(d1 = sum, d2 = mean))

# A tibble: 9 × 6
      x     y    a_d1   b_d1  a_d2  b_d2
  <int> <int>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1  0.0842  0.790     1     1
2     4     2  0.875  NA         1    NA
3     1     2 NA       1.25     NA     1
4     2     2  1.27    0.713     1     1
5     5     1 NA       0.347    NA     1
6     3     2 NA       1.20     NA     1
7     2     1  0.476  NA         1    NA
8     3     1  0.892  NA         1    NA
9     5     2  1.08    1.86      1     1

Be careful: this code returns a tibble obj instead of a data.table obj.
